# Moments of uncorrelated random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be three pairwise uncorrelated random variables
with

$E\left(X\right)=E\left(Y\right)=E\left(Z\right)=0$,

$Var\left(X\right)=Var\left(Y\right)=Var\left(Z\right)=1.$

Is it true that

$E\left[XY^{2}\right]=0$

and

$E\left[XZY^{2}\right]=0?$
I don't know where to start.What kind of results do I need to show this? What are the minimal assumptions we need in order to make the statements true? ?

Thank you

Comment: Independence is a sufficient condition but uncorrelated is not

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example. The discrete joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$
puts probability $1/6$ at the center of each square in the left-hand plot
below. Then $E(X) = E(Y) = E(XY) = 0,$ but $E(X^2Y) \approx .99.$

Thus $Cor(X,Y) = 0,$ but $Cor(X^2,Y)$ is almost $1.$
The plots are from 2000 realizations of these distributions, but
a bit of 'jitter' has been added to each variable to prevent points
plotting on top of one another. 
(Each random variable
can be re-scaled to have unit variance.)

[image]

**By contrast**, if $(X,Y)$ is standard uncorrelated biivariate *normal,* then null correlation implies independence. Thus $X$ and $Y$ are *independent,* and
$X^2$ and $Y$ must be also. (One can verify analytically or illustrate
by simulation that $E(X^2Y) = 0.$) In the right-hand plot below, there is no
obvious association between $X^2$ and $Y$.

[image]

Comment: Not that it matters, but those $X$ and $Y$ do not have variance $1$

Comment: @Henry. Right. Noted in parentheses. I did not re-scale because I thought the example is simpler with integer values.